# Spring Data JPA: Batch insert for nested entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a test case where I need to persist 100'000 entity instances into the database. The code I'm currently using does this, but it takes up to 40 seconds until all the data is persisted in the database. The data is read from a JSON file which is about 15 MB in size.

Now I had already implemented a batch insert method in a custom repository before for another project. However, in that case I had a lot of top level entities to persist, with only a few nested entities.

In my current case I have 5 `Job` entities that contain a List of about ~30 `JobDetail` entities. One `JobDetail` contains between 850 and 1100 `JobEnvelope` entities.

When writing to the database I commit the List of `Job` entities with the default `save(Iterable<Job> jobs)` interface method. All nested entities have the CascadeType `PERSIST`. Each entity has it's own table.

The usual way to enable batch inserts would be to implement a custom method like `saveBatch` that flushes every once in a while. But my problem in this case are the `JobEnvelope` entities. I don't persist them with a `JobEnvelope` repository, instead I let the repository of the `Job`entity handle it. I'm using MariaDB as database server.

So my question boils down to the following: How can I make the `JobRepository` insert it's nested entities in batches?

These are my 3 entites in question:

### Job

```
@Entity
public class Job {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int jobId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "job")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Collection<JobDetail> jobDetails;
}
```

### JobDetail

```
@Entity
public class JobDetail {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int jobDetailId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "jobId")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Job job;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "jobDetail")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<JobEnvelope> jobEnvelopes;
}
```

### JobEnvelope

```
@Entity
public class JobEnvelope {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int jobEnvelopeId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "jobDetailId")
  private JobDetail jobDetail;

  private double weight;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure to configure Hibernate batch-related properties properly:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
```

The point is that successive statements can be batched if they manipulate the same table. If there comes the statement doing insert to another table, the previous batch construction must be interrupted and executed before that statement. With the `hibernate.order_inserts` property you are giving permission to Hibernate to reorder inserts before constructing batch statements (`hibernate.order_updates` has the same effect for update statements).

`jdbc.batch_size` is the maximum batch size that Hibernate will use. Try and analyze different values and pick one that shows best performance in your use cases.

Note that batching of insert statements is [disabled](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html) if `IDENTITY` id generator is used.

Specific to MySQL, you have to specify `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` as part of the connection URL. To make sure that batching is working as expected, add `profileSQL=true` to inspect the SQL the driver sends to the database. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21587949/4754790).

If your entities are versioned (for optimistic locking purposes), then in order to utilize batch updates (doesn't impact inserts) you will have to turn on also:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
```

With this property you tell Hibernate that the JDBC driver is capable to return the correct count of affected rows when executing batch update (needed to perform the version check). You have to check whether this works properly for your database/jdbc driver. For example, it [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519308/hibernate-saves-stale-data-with-hibernate-jdbc-batch-versioned-data) in Oracle 11 and older Oracle versions.

You may also want to flush and clear the persistence context [after each batch](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e1893) to release memory, otherwise all of the managed objects remain in the persistence context until it is closed.

Also, you may find [this blog](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) useful as it nicely explains the details of Hibernate batching mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailled response. So it's basically not possible to do batch inserts on entities that use the ``@GeneratedValue`` annotation?

Comment: It is possible, only it is not possible for `IDENTITY` id generator. Works for any other id generator.

Comment: Ah, I see. It was set to `AUTO`, `SEQUENCE` is not supported by MySQL, so I'm currently looking into `TABLE` generation. Guess the automatic mode selected the `IDENTITY` method since there was no table for sequences and the other one was not supported. Will report back.

Comment: Quite possible, since `native` is default I think if you specify `@GeneratedValue` only, and it first checks if `IDENTITY` is supported by the database.

Comment: Holy moly, thanks a lot - did work wonders. It only takes 5 instead of 40 seconds to insert those 100'000 entries :)

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previous answer of Dragan Bozanovic. Hibernate sometimes silently deactivates the order of execution of the batches if for example it encounters cyclic relations between the entities when it builds the graph of dependencies between the batches (see InsertActionSorter.sort(..) method). It would have been interesting for hibernate to trace this behavior when this happens.