# How to run mysql update batch query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I've got a mysql (SQL) batch query:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 2 WHERE resId = '6hiuxhqkw4s1bta9a';
UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 4 WHERE resId = 'hpvihvzk0vainpkgg';
UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 6 WHERE resId = 'krfswe6wohjtugmtd';
UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 3 WHERE resId = 'tcybuiuulkju5wjre';
UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 7 WHERE resId = 'sgs4gr4v6aepuwdgq';

COMMIT;
```

The above Code is working fine while running on MySQl 5.7 terminal However, I'm trying to run the same query from Hibernate and Hibernate is giving an Exception - "Nested  Query Not Supported".

My Hibernate Code:

```
String queryToBeUpdate = "START TRANSACTION;\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 2 WHERE resId = '6hiuxhqkw4s1bta9a';\n" + 
            "UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 4 WHERE resId = 'hpvihvzk0vainpkgg';\n" + 
            "UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 6 WHERE resId = 'krfswe6wohjtugmtd';\n" + 
            "UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 3 WHERE resId = 'tcybuiuulkju5wjre';\n" + 
            "UPDATE home SET currentSeq = 7 WHERE resId = 'sgs4gr4v6aepuwdgq';\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "COMMIT;";

Query q =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryToBeUpdate);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It might be the case createSQLQuery function doesn't support multiple SQL statements separated with semicons (`;`)

Comment: I don't know whether or not this can done from Hibernate.  It can be done from JDBC, in which case you would turn off auto commit, and then run each update.  The `START TRANSACTION` ... `COMMIT` markers are for raw MySQL, not JDBC.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think you're right.  We can do this directly from JDBC, but in general it probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: if you look into the docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html you can see the `createSQLQuery` is creating a ` SQLQuery?` Object.. I see it's possible to do JOINS but i didn't find a possible way to allow multiple SQL statements..

Comment: @RaymondNijland
Thanks for Responding guys , I'm new to hibernate ,
My task is to update the query in batch using hibernate.
I've tried to do a lot of research on google but don't seem to find an appropriate answer ,as most of the examples are about  "hibernate batch insert"  on internet.

Comment: You can rewrite all update queries into one update query by the way , not a hibernate thing but pure SQL code .. Then you only need to execute three queries..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you're right when you said that it can't be done from hibernate.
I think my problem is somewhat similar like to this :--

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033896/hibernate-hql-execute-multiple-update-statements-in-same-query

Comment: @Sumit The good news is that usually you don't need to do this (otherwise Hibernate would have supported it).  You can always call a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine an UPDATE with a CASE like this:

```
String queryToBeUpdate = "UPDATE home SET currentSeq = (CASE 
                          WHEN  resId = '6hiuxhqkw4s1bta9a' THEN '2' 
                          WHEN  resId = 'hpvihvzk0vainpkgg' THEN '4' 
                          WHEN  resId = 'krfswe6wohjtugmtd' THEN '6' 
                          WHEN  resId = 'tcybuiuulkju5wjre' THEN '3' 
                          WHEN  resId = 'sgs4gr4v6aepuwdgq' THEN '7' 
                          END)
                          WHERE resId IN(6hiuxhqkw4s1bta9a,hpvihvzk0vainpkgg,krfswe6wohjtugmtd,tcybuiuulkju5wjre,sgs4gr4v6aepuwdgq) ";
 SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(strq);
 query.executeUpdate(queryToBeUpdate);
```

(AS BULK UPDATE QUERY)